# Keep on getting a "Cannot find symbol" on my simple Java program and don't know why

Tags: java

So, here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class FootballsGivenAway

{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {

   int FinalScore;
   **int TouchdownNumber=BallsGivenAway;**
   int BallsGivenAway=TouchdownNumber;


   Scanner inputDevice= new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("What was the final score of the Carolina Panthers? ");
   FinalScore=inputDevice.nextInt();
   System.out.print("Out of the points the Panthers scored, how many of them were touchdowns? ");
   TouchdownNumber=inputDevice.nextInt();


   System.out.println("The Carolina Panthers gave away this number of footballs today: " + BallsGivenAway);

   }
}
```

The compiler keeps returning the "Cannot find symbol" error on the line in bold. What must I do to correct this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a local variable in Java before you've declared it. If you look at your code, you can see that you're trying to set `TouchdownNumber` to `BallsGivenAway` before you've declared `BallsGivenAway` on the next line.

Also:

- You're trying to set `BallsGivenAway` back to `TouchDownNumber`? You're defining two variables whose value is supposed to be ... the other one?
- Idiomatic Java uses camelCase variable names like finalScore, ballsGivenAway. It's just a style issue, but you might as well get used to it now.